# Rails pass data to form for different model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, rest, formtastic

I have two models, `Users` and `Shifts`.

- `Users`: id, name
- `Shifts`: user_id, time_length

`User` has_many `Shifts`; `Shift` belongs_to `User`. Fairly simple.

What I want to do is add a button on my `show` user controller (`/users/1`) that links to the new `Shift` controller view (`/shifts/new`). I've managed to do this with a button, as I want to pre-populate the form with the information from my `Users` model (i.e. send across the `user.id`).

I'm using the following code, which is linking fine, but can't work out how to pass the `user.id` details

```
button_to "Create Shift", {:controller => "shifts", :action => "new"},{ :method => "get"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in extra parameters to the second argument like so:

```rb
button_to "Create Shift", { :controller => "shifts", :action => "new", :user_id => user.id }, { :method => "get" }
```

This should generate a URL like `/shifts/new?user_id=5`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources):

In routes.rb write:

```
map.resources :users do |users|
  users.resources :shifts
end
```

Then the path for the new shift form would be `new_user_shift_path` = `/users/:id/shift/new`

And in the `shifts_controller` you can get the user like this:

```
@user = User.find(params[:user_id])
```

Then you put it in your form as a hidden tag field. (Or it won't be necessary - I don't know exactly)